# Crash in ID3DXConstantTable SetFloat/SetVector

Tags: direct3d, application-verifier

We have a application with a render engine developed in Direct3d/C++. Recently we have come across a crash( access violation) involving   ID3DXConstantTable SetFloat/SetVector and shows inside D3dx9_42.dll when we attached a debugger in release binaries with PDBs. One of the ways this crash vanishes when we reduce the number of D3dPOOL Rendertarget textures which are used but from estimating the GPU memory load its no where close to even half of the total available  as we are using 3GB NVIDIA cards.

Suspected it to be some heap corruptions due to memory overwrites we went about code checking and following that we used the Application Verifier along with a debugger to root out of memory overwrites which might crash at a later stage of running.. We came across few issues which we ironed out. But still that crash remains at the very first frame render ID3DXConstantTable SetFloat/SetVector . More info :This is 32 bit application running with LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag.   Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Well a moment later only i found out the issue I executed the application with the registry switch MEM_TOP_DOWN(AllocationPreference=0x100000) and it instantly crashed at the first setfloat() location.Then goto to know the constant table had to be retrieved using D3DXGetShaderConstantTableEx() with the D3DXCONSTTABLE_LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag :) Thanks

Comment: LAA is useful, but it's a hack. There was some rudimentary support put into the legacy Effects system to support LAA as you have noted (``D3DXFX_LARGEADDRESSAWARE`` as well), but really the best thing is to move to x64 native (and Direct3D 11). Effects (FX9) hijacks the hi bit of the address to indicate a HANDLE vs. a pointer.